# How to setup existing TYPO3 project in our local machine?

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I am newbie to TYPO3 and having a situation where I have to setup an existing TYPO3 website in my local machine so, I can make changes in some pages but the problem is that I don't have any experience with TYPO3.

**What I have:**

I have FTP access to the development server but don't know which folders/files are required to make it work in the local machine.

**What I have tried:**

I had searched regarding this on the internet and also read some past StackOverflow questions but don't find any positive response.

If someone can guide me through then it would be very helpful... Thanks!

Comment: "_What I have tried?_" / "_I readed_"... What have you try on your server? There are several lists of things to do while moving TYPO3 installation that can be googled by "how to move TYPO3 to another server", in general, you need to create **working** VHOST at your local machine, copy files there and copy the database to your local. wich steps of these you already did? Please list them in updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first: you need a webserver running PHP and a database (probably mySQL).
This should match the running server.

You might use DDEV to put it all into a virtual machine and get a better match, but any webserver with PHP and mysql should do.

TYPO3 can be running in two ways:

- composer mode
- non composer mode

if it runs in composer mode you also need composer (and git) installed. But the copy is easier as you only need to copy the `composer.lock`-file and do an `composer install` to copy all code.

additional you need to copy all data.

1. that is the database.
2. the whole folder `/fileadmin` (based in webroot)

---

in non-composer mode you need to:

- install the same TYPO3 version (typical somewhere with a symlink `/typo3/ -> your location/` in the webroot.
- then look for `/index.php` on the original server and copy it (it could be a symlink)
- additional you need to copy the folder `/typo3conf` from the server.
- and of course the data as above

---

then you might need to adapt `/typo3conf/LocalConfiguration.php` and `/typo3conf/AddionalConfiguration.php`. (database credentials/ domain specific info/ ...)
since TYPO3 9 you probably have a yaml config file outside the webroot.